# Cannot connect to Azure SQL database using AAD from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

Our devops guys has recently enabled AAD authentication in our Azure SQL Servers and added my identity (say *my.identity@mycompany.com*) as a dbo to *MyDatabase*. I can successfully connect to the database using SSMS and now I want to connect using the same identity from my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;

namespace AzureADAuth {
    class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/");

            Principal principal = azureServiceTokenProvider.PrincipalUsed;
            Console.WriteLine($"AppId: {principal.AppId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"IsAuthenticated: {principal.IsAuthenticated}");
            Console.WriteLine($"TenantId: {principal.TenantId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Type: {principal.Type}");
            Console.WriteLine($"UserPrincipalName: {principal.UserPrincipalName}");

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=########.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;")) {
                connection.AccessToken = accessToken;
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                var command = new SqlCommand("select CURRENT_USER", connection);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
                    await reader.ReadAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Here is the output:

```
AppId:
IsAuthenticated: True
TenantId: ########-####-####-bc14-789b44d11a3c
Type: User
UserPrincipalName: my.identity@mycompany.com

Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, Sq
lConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTr
ansientFaultHandling)
```

`AzureServiceTokenProvider` successfully grabs my identity from Azure CLI but the SQL login fails. What am I missing?

**P.S.**

I'm targeting .NET full framework 4.7; `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` package is the latest, 1.0.1; my machine is not joined to any domain (not sure if it's important as I don't need AAD integrated auth, only token based)

Comment: Why use Token auth, instead of "Active Directory - Integrated" or "Active Directory - Password" like SSMS uses?

Comment: My final goal after the test is switching to Managed Service Identities so as I understand neither Password nor Integrated auth options will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `database.windows.net` instead of `management.azure.com`
 option,

```
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who has this issue - I scoured multiple resources where users had this exact issue without a solution that worked.  However, was able to finally resolve my issue by adding the 'tenant' of where my SQL database resided.  Since I had multiple Azure subscriptions.

In the above code to grab the token:

```
return provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
```

I needed to add the tenant as well:

```
return provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", "hosttenant.onmicrosoft.com");
```